# {strip} template function with max line length

Tags: php, smarty

I have a large block of html text saved in the database, when I output this to the page and use `{strip}` its exceeding the Outlook line limit and breaking the HTML.

1. In PHP what is the best performance way to echo a block of text ensuring its within a specified character width
2. Is there a way to add this into the smarty `{strip}` function as a param: `{strip length=1000}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/wordwrap) function does what you want in (1).